# How to enlarge "/"?

Tags: linux, lvm

I'm using Red Hat 6.3 MP with two disks:

```
VMware virtual disc (sda) with:
  /boot (sda1)
  swap (sda2)
  lvm2-disc (sda3)
/dev/dm-0 mounted on /
```

On `/dev/dm-0`, there is no free space available. `/dm-0` is a logical volume.

When I run `lvextend -L12G /dev/mapper/LogVol0` , it will inform  me with a **Insufficient free space: 1792 extents needed, but only 0 available** message.

Is it possible to enlarge my root partition, `/`? My Volume Group has enough space left.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can and usually you can do it online if you have LVM. Here is RH article how to do this: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/lv_extend.html

Comment: While this may help solve the problem, it would be preferable to include the relevant parts in your answer, and provide a link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I only see one disk (sda). ;)

The general procedure would be among the lines of the following:

1. Increase virtual disk size in your VMware product
2. Resize partition containing LVM Physical Volume to fill the disk
3. Resize the LVM Physical Volume to fill the partition
4. Resize the LVM Logical Volume to utilize the newly gained space in your Volume Group.

Alternatively, you can also add another Physical Volume (even on a different (virtual) disk) to your Volume Group and start at step 4.

Comment: Thank you both! Instead of step one I just added a new virtual disk in VMware. The link from Chris got me all through the resizing steps. Thats all :)